kubernetes configure traefikv3 to act as an ingress provider
I got a kubernetes cluster running and I would like to expose a service.
I have a TestApplication that runs on port TestPort 3000.
How do I configure Traefik to act as an ingress provider?
in the documentation I don't understand where do I have to specify
providers:
  kubernetesIngress: {}


source: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-ingress/
Is that enough to specify that it has to act as a kubernetes ingress?
    kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-deployment
  labels:
    app: traefik

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-account
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v3.2
          args:
            - --api.insecure
            - --providers.kubernetesingress
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
            - name: dashboard
              containerPort: 8080


I will edit the question because I can see it is a bit vague.

The "Getting Started with Kubernetes" walks through the process. For traefik to act as an Ingress provider, you need:

A ServiceAccount
A ClusterRole
A ClusterRoleBinding
A Deployment
An IngressClass

The easiest way to get all this set up is by using the official helm chart. Using helm, installing traefik looks like:
helm repo add traefik https://traefik.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm install traefik traefik/traefik

You can also run helm template traefik/traefik to generate the manifests on stdout if you want to inspect them.
